# Adding icons to bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an icon to a bootstrap button. Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"<i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>>Default</button>
```

I tried with fontawesome but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a very small mistake here. You have to close the first button tag before the button starts.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Default</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Default</button>
```

You mistyped the closing tag of the button. The I element should be inside the button element.